# Why does a scanf look like it changes the behaviour of char*?

Tags: c, scanf

I've the following code wich I find hard to understand why it works the way it does:

```
char* str = "HELLO";
printf("%s",&str[0]); //Returns Hello as expected
printf("%c",str[2]); //Returns L as aspected
scanf("%s",&str); //I enter aaaa
printf("%s\n",&str); /* If I want to access the word I have to do this way
&str[0] now gives a segmentation fault.*/
printf("%c\n",&str[1]); /*This gives a b???!!!. I haven't found any way to 
access individual character with *str.*/
```

I'm specially interested in why there looks to be no way to access the individual characters, although in some way it makes sense, after all you are supposed to be declaring a pointer to char, I wonder how it can work as a string in some way. But I'd like to know why the first one works as an array of characters as expected and not the second one.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a) compiler warnings, and b) a good manual.

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler and treat them as errors.

Comment: @user2638180: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s",&str);` invokes undefined behavior: you ask `scanf` to read a string and store it into the location of the `str` pointer itself, not the location it points to, which is a string literal that should not be modified either.